# Calculation Not Displaying Proper Answer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I am sure this results from an incorrect parenthesis on my part or something silly like such, but for the life of me I can not get this syntax accurate.  Here is sample DDL

```
Declare @Hold Table
(
val1 float
,val2 float
,val3 float
,val4 float
,val5 float
,val6 float
,val7 float
)

 Insert Into @Hold values
 (145, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60)

 Select
 (val1-(val2+val3+val4+val5+val6+(val7*.22)))/val1
 FROM @Hold
```

So for a breakdown of what I am after with the equation:

```
val1 = 145
val2+val3+val4+val5+val6 = 150
val7 = 60
val7 * .22 = 13
```

Which takes us to this equation:

```
145-(150)+13/145
8/145
```

**My desired output is**
`.055172` or 6%

However my code above produces this as the answer:

```
-0.12551724137931
```

What do I need to alter in order to get my above %?

Comment: val7*.22 is inside the summation parentheses, which means it gets subtracted instead of added. You have 145 - (150+13)

Comment: like @Forrest said, `(val1-(val2+val3+val4+val5+val6)+(val7*.22))/val1` should get you where you're going.

Comment: @SqlZim & Forrest - yes both of you are correct and that produced the accurate outcome

Comment: ' (13 * 0.22)'  there is no 13 value in your table

Comment: @mcNets - val7 = 60
val7 * .22 = 13

Comment: val7 in my table = 60 so the calculation would be 60 * .22 = 13

Comment: which is the desired final value?

Comment: @mcNets - desired final value is .055172 or 6%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comments:

> This is what I am trying to accomplish (145-(150+(13*0.22)))/145 –
>   SmallFries BigGuys

But there isn't none val7 = 13 in your data values.

Check it here: http://rextester.com/RUUZFP27467

```
Declare @Hold Table
(
val1 float
,val2 float
,val3 float
,val4 float
,val5 float
,val6 float
,val7 float
)

 Insert Into @Hold values
 (145, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 13)

 Select
 (val1-(val2+val3+val4+val5+val6+(val7*.22)))/val1
 FROM @Hold
```

> The result is: -0,0542068965517242

Comment: val7 = 60
val7 * .22 = 13

Comment: That should read 60*.22

Answer (score 1):

In addition to correcting the parentheses, if you want your output to be `.055172` then you should cast `(val7*.22)` as an integer in your equation.

http://rextester.com/SQP94408

```
Declare @Hold Table (val1 float,val2 float,val3 float,val4 float,val5 float,val6 float,val7 float)
Insert Into @Hold values (145, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60)
Select
 ( 
   (val1)
  -(val2+val3+val4+val5+val6)
  + (cast((val7*.22) as int)) -- this results in 13
  )  /val1
FROM @Hold 
/* results in 0.0551724137931034 */

Select
 ( 
   (val1)
  -(val2+val3+val4+val5+val6)
  +(val7*.22)  -- this results in 13.20 not 13
  )  /val1
FROM @Hold 

/* results in 0.056551724137931 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about using floats?

```
create table t (f float)
insert into t(f) values (-1.3),(-1.6),(-0.1),(3)

select sum(f) from t
```

> -4.44089209850063E-16

Comment: I had not seen this situation yet...what type should I use here?

Comment: Decimal/Numeric (synonyms - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx). You will have to determine the desired precision and scale in advance (which is a good thing to do)

Comment: I usually use decimal(10,2) but in this instance I used float instead.  Thank you for pointing out I need to stick with decimal(10,2)

Comment: If you think that's bad, use `money` with division. http://stackoverflow.com/a/582819/2333499